# Can't write image data to path

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo este error que al parecer es de permisos

Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException: Can't write image data to path (categories\prueba1_384.png) in file C:\laragon\www...\vendor\intervention\image\src\Intervention\Image\Image.php on line 150

este es el controlador donde se gestiona la carga de las imágenes a la api

```
Public function store (Request $request){
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' =>'required',
            'client_id' =>'required',
            'course_order_enabled' =>'',
            'url_image' => 'required',
            'order' => '',
            'ismain' => ''
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()]);
         } 
         else{
        $category = Category::create([
            'name' =>$request->name,
            'description' =>$request->description,
            'client_id' =>$request->client_id,
            'course_order_enabled' =>$request->course_order_enabled
        ]);

        //384
        $image = image::make($request->url_image);
        $image -> resize(384,384);
        $image -> save('categories'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$request->name.'_384.png');
```

Tengo el proyecto en mi local, en realidad no sé qué debo hacer para solucionar este error. Muchas gracias,

Comment: ¿Existe la carpeta `categories` y está en el mismo nivel del script en ejecución? Lo más recomendable es usar rutas absolutas.

Comment: Si señor, si existe la carpeta
C:\laragon\www\myp\public\images\categories

Comment: antes de guardar la imagen agrega `echo getcwd();` para ver el directorio de trabajo actual y dinos qué aparece, por favor.

Comment: aparece ->     C:\laragon\www\myp\public

Comment: Entonces: `$image -> save('images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'categories' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $request->name.'_384.png');` debería resolver el problema.

Comment: Siiiii, muchísimas gracias :)